# how to set active on angularjs bootstrap tab with static content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using Angular Bootstrap UI to show a tabset with static content. The bootstrap script I include is ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.6.0.min.js.

here is my markup:

```
<tabset>
    <tab ng-show="$parent.hideme" ng-class="{active:$parent.hideme}">
        <tab-heading>
            tab1
        </tab-heading>
        <div>
            tab content 1
        </div>
    </tab>
    <tab ng-hide="$parent.hideme" ng-class="{active:!$parent.hideme}">
        <tab-heading>
            tab2
        </tab-heading>
        <div>
            tab content 2
        </div>
    </tab>
</tabset>
```

Here is the controller

```
function myController($scope) {
    $scope.hideme = false;
});
```

If I don't have ng-class applied on the tab, it works well except that when the 1st tab hide and 2nd tab show ($scope.hideme = false), the content of the 1st tab will show avtive.

If I added ng-class, it caused an error in angularjs. Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=16&p3=%7Bactive%3Afalse%7D%20%7Bactive%3A%20active%2C%20disabled%3A%20disabled%7D&p4=%7Bactive%3A%20active%2C%20disabled%3A%20disabled%7D

What is the right way(or right syntax) to make the specific tab active?

Comment: Not sure why you are using $parent....can you include more of your HTML & Angular code?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend not trying to do the show/hide logic.  I was also frustrated by this because the [UI Bootstrap Tab documentation](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs) only shows navigation to tabs created by binding with ng-repeat.

But I believe you can reference the tabs in the tabset directive as $parentScope.tabs.  So simple navigation is possible using `$parent.tabs[2].select()`:

```
<tabset>
  <tab heading="Tab 1">
    <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="$parent.tabs[2].select()">Go to Tab 3</button>
  </tab>
  <tab heading="Tab 2">
    <p>Tab 2 contents</p>
  </tab>
  <tab heading="Tab 3">
    <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="$parent.tabs[0].select()">Back to Tab 1</button>
  </tab>
</tabset>
```

I have a [working Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/OwQD53sHgCt7bIeCD3P0?p=preview) if that helps.

Comment: HI.. thanks for answer... this is working with older version of bootstrap.. 
and in current version it's not..

Comment: @Nisar, which versions of bootstrap, angular and ui-bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I am using (0.14.3) version of ui-bootstrap.. I have also made a Plunker of it ... http://plnkr.co/edit/kzg9ITOiubLuZwkw3TmY?p=preview

Comment: I think you may have version incompatibilities between Angular 1.2.x and ui-bootstrap 0.14.3, which I believe works only with Angular 1.3.x and higher (see [Milestones](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/wiki/Milestones)). I made a [modified Plunk with the updated version](http://plnkr.co/edit/2G7FL2iqH8iAGVWpV4ay?p=preview), and it seems to work again.

Comment: anyone has any idea how to make a tab active programmatically? for example on click of a button??