# angularjs: what event I should use after a template is rendered?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, angular-template

I am using routes with template html

```
$routeProvider.when('/newroute',
{
templateUrl: 'template/newroute.html',
controller: 'myController'
});
```

I need to do something to manipulate the DOM using jquery after the template html is rendered (I know it is not good practice, but I could not find the answer to my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104289/how-to-set-active-on-angularjs-bootstrap-tab-with-static-content))

However, I could not find the right event that happens right after the template html is rendered.
I tried following, which does not work.

```
$scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
   doSomething(); //does not work
});
```

When I debug into viewContentLoaded, the template html DOM is still invisible.  Any ideas?

Comment: not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish, need more info!

Comment: Sounds like you want to use a custom directive.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I ended up solving it by using `setTimeout` to run some jQuery

```
                setTimeout(function () {
                var l=$('.accordion-section').length;
                if(l>0){
                    $('.accordion-section').equalHeights();
                }
            },500);
```

I put the setTimout call into the initialization of my controller.
There are some other answers here but `$timeout` did not work for me.
[AngularJS: How to run additional code after AngularJS has rendered a template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304291/angularjs-how-to-run-additional-code-after-angularjs-has-rendered-a-template)