# Active on angularjs bootstrap tab with static content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I am using Angular Bootstrap UI to show a tabset with static content.

I was frustrated by this because the UI Bootstrap Tab documentation only shows navigation to tabs created by binding with ng-repeat.

```
    <uib-tabset>
        <uib-tab heading="Basic Details">
            <div role=" tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="basicDetails">
            tab1
            <button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="$parent.tabs[1].select()">Go to Tab 3</button>
            </div>
        </uib-tab>
        <uib-tab heading="Basic Details">
            <div role=" tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="basicDetails">
            tab2
            </div>
        </uib-tab>
    </uib-tabset>
```

I found some thing  hear [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26875750/2545270) but this is not working with current version of Angular Bootstrap UI..

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/kzg9ITOiubLuZwkw3TmY?p=preview)

Comment: I see the next and previous buttons are not working in your plunker. Is that correct or is it just me?

Answer (score 5):

to set a tab as active, you need to set a boolean flag on your scope to "true" and associate it with the given tab's `active` attribute.  this would look like

```
<uib-tabset>
    <uib-tab heading="Basic Details" active="tabOneActive">
        tab1
    </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab heading="Other Details" active="tabTwoActive">
       tab2
    </uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

when `tabOneActive` is set to true, the first tab will be shown

Comment: update my question.. added plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/kzg9ITOiubLuZwkw3TmY?p=preview

Comment: This no longer works, instead you have to set the active property on the uib-tabset element to the index of the active tab. See http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/versioned-docs/1.3.1/

Comment: It no longer works in new versions, right, but if you have to work with an outdated version then this answer is really useful -> +1

Comment: @MarkusPscheidt, I don't think there is a valid reason not to work with the newest stable version of UI Bootstrap always!

Comment: @DSF No valid reason in a perfect world ;) We were a bit behind with our updatrs..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the cleanest solution, but I ended up with manually switching tabs by click on headings:

```
<uib-tabset>
    <uib-tab heading="h1" active="h1Active" ng-click="h1Active=true">
     ... content 1
    <uib-tab>
    <uib-tab heading="h2" active="!h1Active" ng-click="h1Active=false">
     ... content 2
    <uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

I have just two tabs here, and one variale is enough to switch between. But in case of more tabs I guess you just have to implement little more complicated login on click. I mean, probably, set one to true and others to false.